# How can I create an On-Demand DynamoDB table in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb

I cannot seem to find an example of creating an **On-Demand** `DynamoDB` table in `C#`.

The `C#` examples on `AWS` only [describes](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetWorkingWithTables.html#LowLeveldotNetCreateTable) how to create a table with provisioned throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the way this is supported in the SDK is unintuitive.

One would need to first create a table with a default `ProvisionedThroughput` then update the table and set the billing to: `PAY_PER_REQUEST`

```
CreateTableRequest createRequest = new CreateTableRequest 
{
    TableName = "Foo",
    AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition> {
        new AttributeDefinition {
            AttributeName = "Id",
            AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S,
        }
    }, 
    KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement> {
        new KeySchemaElement("Id", KeyType.HASH)
    }, 
    ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput(1, 1)
};

await client.CreateTableAsync(createRequest);
// Wait for it to be created

await client.UpdateTableAsync(new UpdateTableRequest
{
    TableName = name,
    BillingMode = BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised by @MaYaN's answer, I've got it working nicely with

```
CreateTableRequest createRequest = new CreateTableRequest 
{
    TableName = "Foo",
    AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition> {
        new AttributeDefinition {
            AttributeName = "Id",
            AttributeType = ScalarAttributeType.S,
        }
    }, 
    KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement> {
        new KeySchemaElement("Id", KeyType.HASH)
    }, 
    BillingMode = BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST
};
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks for the answer.